# Backbone.js Large mutli page app, manage page transitions cleanly destruction, creation etc

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js

I'm currently building a huge backbone app (facebook clone).

Over the last couple of days, feeling pretty happy with how everything works in BB thanks to Rob Conery's excelent tutorial (essential viewing if your starting out with MVC 3 and BB http://tekpub.com/productions/mvc3)

Now I've come to the stage where I need to switch pages in my app, and I am starting to wire this up, but it feels like I'm doing a lot of this myself. This is fine, and I know I will be able to do what I want it to.

I've delt with the memory leaking issues, by making sure I unbind and remove my models/collections/views when switching page, [Switching views in backbone for navigating between pages - whats the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250759/switching-views-in-backbone-for-navigating-between-pages-whats-the-right-way)

But aside from this stuff, there is a whole load of tasks that I want to do when I switch between pages. Essentially removing and adding parts of the page. This is slightly more complicated becuase rather than just removing everything, I'd like to only remove/destory the bits of the page that need to change, based on the transition I'd like to make.

As said, I'm getting it working myself at the moment, but I wondered if there was a pattern to handle this tear up / tear down process, and keep things clean (and not end up with a massively bloated router (controller bloat!!!)

Comment: Is this the best answer? https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette

Comment: Or this perhaps, http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/03/22/managing-layouts-and-nested-views-with-backbone-marionette/#comment-2375

Comment: Marionette is a nice framework. You may also want to checkout the backbone.layoutmanager https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager#readme

Comment: What did you actually use in the end?

Comment: This project stayed in backbone, and it was fine. But I probably wouldn't use backbone again, becuase of the way it forces you to wrap your data. Used angular a lot, but a lot of people don't like that, becuase it is too kitchen sink. I just tried out VueJS and I think it seems really good for a lot of reasons http://vuejs.org/guide/comparison.html Also, I highly recomend considering if you need a framework at all - https://muut.com/blog/technology/frameworkless-javascript.html

Answer (score 9):

Marionette is definitely the way to go.  Specifically, [Marionette.Layout](http://derickbailey.github.com/backbone.marionette/#marionette-layout) is fantastic for swapping out specific regions without re-rendering the entire page.  Check out some of Derick's [Example Apps](http://derickbailey.github.com/backbone.marionette/#backbone-marionette-sample-apps) to get acquainted with the framework.

I'd recommend staying away from the Router until after you've gotten your app working using plain old events.  Then add the Router support after.  Basically the Router should be wired up to reflect the state of your app, but you should not depend on it to be your controller.

As an aside, I'm using RequrieJS on a large multi-module Backbone project and it's been a godsend.  It's controversial in the BB community, but it's worth looking into if you'll have lots of inter-dependent components and you want to let another framework handle all the dependencies.

Comment: Like Dave pointed out in this answer, the Layout will help. Specifically, the Marionette.Region object will do the cleanup when swapping out views. Layouts are views that have embedded Regions in them.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm knee deep in marionette right now. It's been an odd week of gearing up with backbone first, hitting brick walls, and then getting all sorted. For a while with marionette it felt like being back at square one, but what I did was replicate http://bbclonemail.heroku.com/#inbox in my local environment, and have just finished extending it to have a 3rd app within it (cloning the mail app) Feels really good to be laying everything out in such a clean way. Do you think there are any downsides to using it?

Comment: The only downside that I see is the mental overhead of learning another layer of abstraction on top of Backbone.  But once you wrap your head around Marionette, you'll start thinking in terms of these higher-level concepts, and you'll find yourself writing less of the same boilerplate code.  Stick with it, and it'll be worth it!

Answer (score 0):

I had your same problem and wanted to share how I solved it, so I re-designed the ToDo App example from the Backbone.js docs using my page transition convention:

http://ahamlett.com/Backbone.localStorage/

I haven't tested it for memory leaks, but if there are some just call .unbind() before .remove() in the SetView method of the app's router.